How can i combine a parallax scroll and page scroll in reactjs
I was building a website and specifically portfolio. i included and parallax effect and its working  good and i wanted and object to rotate while scrolling and i set that too but then i realised parallax scrolling is separate from normal scrolling. as shown below

How can i make the parallax and rotate to work together
I was trying for a rotating object while scrolling but it didn't work
